# How to deploy application in OpenShift 3?

Tags: openshift

Using this [tutorial](https://blog.openshift.com/private-git-repositories-part-5-hosting-repositories-bitbucket/) for using private `Node.js` repo from `BitBucket` in `OpenShift`, in last command getting an error, why?

```
Kukodas-MBP:~ kukodajanos$ ./oc new-app httpd~git@bitbucket.org:j4nos/nodejs.git --name mysite
error: Errors occurred while determining argument types:

httpd~git@bitbucket.org:j4nos/nodejs.git as a local directory pointing to a Git repository:  stat httpd~git@bitbucket.org:j4nos/nodejs.git: no such file or directory
```

[image]

```
Errors occurred during resource creation:
error: the image match "httpd" for source repository "git@bitbucket.org:j4nos/nodejs.git" does not appear to be a source-to-image builder.

- to attempt to use this image as a source builder, pass "--strategy=source"
- to use it as a base image for a Docker build, pass "--strategy=docker"
```

---

Changed `httpd` to `nodejs`, I am using for repo name, and so it works:

```
Kukodas-MBP:~ kukodajanos$ ./oc new-app nodejs~git@bitbucket.org:j4nos/nodejs.git --name mysite
--> Found image cd02d02 (3 weeks old) in image stream "openshift/nodejs" under tag "6" for "nodejs"

    Node.js 6 
    --------- 
    Node.js 6 available as docker container is a base platform for building and running various Node.js 6 applications and frameworks. Node.js is a platform built on Chrome's JavaScript runtime for easily building fast, scalable network applications. Node.js uses an event-driven, non-blocking I/O model that makes it lightweight and efficient, perfect for data-intensive real-time applications that run across distributed devices.

    Tags: builder, nodejs, nodejs6

    * A source build using source code from ssh://git@bitbucket.org/j4nos/nodejs.git will be created
      * The resulting image will be pushed to image stream "mysite:latest"
      * Use 'start-build' to trigger a new build
    * This image will be deployed in deployment config "mysite"
    * Port 8080/tcp will be load balanced by service "mysite"
      * Other containers can access this service through the hostname "mysite"

--> Creating resources ...
    imagestream "mysite" created
    buildconfig "mysite" created
    deploymentconfig "mysite" created
```

Comment: You possibly don't have an image stream, or not one marked as a builder, in your OpenShift cluster globally, or in your project, called ``httpd``. What exactly are you wanting to do? Deploy a Node application, or a static web site?

Comment: Deploy a Node.js application. Have a Node.js code in BitBucket, but in a private account. Need to build it, so need set up credentials in OpenShift.

Comment: Use ``nodejs`` instead of ``httpd`` in the command and see if you get further.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton still having problems! How to set credentials? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46424770/how-to-create-app-with-openshift

Comment: What is the syntacs of this line? `./oc new-app httpd~git@bitbucket.org:j4nos/nodejs.git --name mysite`

Comment: What is the error you are getting in the build logs now? The command format when you used ``nodejs`` instead of ``httpd`` is fine. To understand more about ``oc new-app`` and ways of using it, suggest you work through exercises at https://learn.openshift.com and read the free eBook at https://www.openshift.com/promotions/for-developers.html