# How to create app with credentials in OpenShift?

Tags: openshift

Try to create `Node.js` app in `OpenShift` in terminal, like this:

`./oc new-app https://j4nos@bitbucket.org/j4nos/nodejs.git`

Source code in `BitBucket` in a private account, how to set credentials? Once it asked for password, but not again. How can I set credentials?

[image]

---

Added annotated secret from GUI: `repo-at-bitbucket`

[image]

I have read [Private Git Repositories: Part 2A](https://blog.openshift.com/private-git-repositories-part-2a-repository-ssh-keys/) tutorial, strange that for `HTTPD` app there is a `Source Secret` filed to select secret, but not when `Node.js` + `MongoDB` combo is selected. Why?

---

Ahh .. need to select pure `Node.js` app.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to authenticate to the private git repository.  This can be done a few different ways.  I would suggest taking a few a minutes and reading this blog series which outlines the different methods you can take.

https://blog.openshift.com/private-git-repositories-part-1-best-practices/

After reading first through initial few posts explaining concepts and doing it with GitHub, only then look at the BitBucket example.

https://blog.openshift.com/private-git-repositories-part-5-hosting-repositories-bitbucket/

Those GitHub examples have more explanation which will then make BitBucket example easier to understand.

The likely reason you were prompted for the password when running `oc new-app` is that you used:

```
oc new-app https://j4nos@bitbucket.org/j4nos/nodejs.git
```

Specifically, you didn't specify a S2I builder to use. As a result, `oc new-app` will try and checkout the repo locally to analyse it to try and work out what language it uses. This is why it would prompt for the password separately.

It is better to specify the builder name on the command as:

```
oc new-app nodejs~https://j4nos@bitbucket.org/j4nos/nodejs.git
```

This is an abbreviated form of the command and is the same as running:

```
oc new-app --strategy=source --image-stream nodejs --code https://j4nos@bitbucket.org/j4nos/nodejs.git
```

If you specify the builder, it already knows what to use and doesn't analyse the code so will not prompt for the password, plus you wouldn't need user in the URI.

Either way, when building in OpenShift you still need the `basicauth` secret and should annotate it so it knows to use the secret for that build.

Comment: the two methods suggested for specifying the builder might not be exactly the same 

`oc new-app --image-stream=php:5.5 --strategy=source --code=https://<private-bitbucket-repo>/git/web_cn.git --context-dir=php-webcn --source-secret=vajra-bitbucket`  


is still trying to clone and analyse the repo,  prompting for bitbucket credentials 

while the short hand method  below works as expected 
i.e without prompting credentials 

`oc new-app php:5.5~https://<private-bitbucket-repo>/git//web_cn.git --context-dir=php-webcn --source-secret=vajra-bitbucket`